# Bash alias using !$

Tags: bash

I found out today that I can write `!$` to get the last argument from the last command executed.

Now I'm trying to create an alias using that shortcut and it isn't working at all.

These are the ones I'm trying to create.

```
alias gal='git add !$'
alias gcl='git checkout !$'
alias sl='sublime !$'
```

And this is the result output when calling `gal` or `gcl`

```
fatal: pathspec '!$' did not match any files
```

So it seems like `!$` just isn't being replaced by the last argument from the last command in this context.

Is it possible?

Comment: Since Bash expands `!$`, there is no way it can be "stored" somewhere to be used later on. I think it would make more sense to say `alias gal="git add"` and then call it with the `!$` in it --> `gal !$`.

Comment: @fedorqui That's definitely the best option.

Comment: why don't you use the variable [`$_`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0024_005f)?

Comment: @fedorqui That would defeat the purpose.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks! Works like a charm. If you would write it as an answer, I'll glady accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fiddling with Bash's history, you might as well want to use [Bash's `$_` internal variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0024_005f): The relevant part of the manual states:

> `$_`: […] expands to the last argument to the previous command, after expansion. […]

For example:

```
$ touch one two three
$ echo "$_"
three
$ ls
$ echo "$_"
ls
$ a='hello world'
$ echo $a
hello world
$ echo "$_"
world
$ echo "$a"
hello world
$ echo "$_"
hello world
$
```

In your case, your aliases would look like:

```
alias gal='git add "$_"'
alias gcl='git checkout "$_"'
alias sl='sublime "$_"'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bash builtin history command `fc`: an example

```
$ alias re_echo='echo $(fc -ln -2 | awk '\''NR==1 {print $NF}'\'')'
$ echo foo
foo
$ re_echo bar
foo bar
$ re_echo baz
bar baz
$ re_echo qux
baz qux
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-1` or else you'll be outputting two commands ago ?

Comment: I thought so too, but then I tested it and saw that, with "-1", the last word of the *current* command was used. I wonder if the alias is already somehow on the history stack by the time fc is being executed? Dunno.